# docker-compose: postgres data not persisting

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, docker, boot2docker, docker-compose

I have a main service in my `docker-compose` file that uses `postgres`'s image and, though I seem to be successfully connecting to the database, the data that I'm writing to it is not being kept beyond the lifetime of the container (what I did is based on [this tutorial](http://www.andreagrandi.it/2015/02/21/how-to-create-a-docker-image-for-postgresql-and-persist-data/)).

Here's my `docker-compose` file:

```
main:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  links:
    - postgresdb
  command: python manage.py insert_into_database
  environment:
    - DEBUG=true


postgresdb:
  build: utils/sql/
  volumes_from:
    - postgresdbdata
  ports:
    - "5432"
  environment:
    - DEBUG=true


postgresdbdata:
  build: utils/sql/
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
  command: true
  environment:
    - DEBUG=true
```

and here's the Dockerfile I'm using for the `postgresdb` and `postgresdbdata` services (which essentially creates the database and adds a user):

```
FROM postgres

ADD make-db.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

How can I get the data to stay after the `main` service has finished running, in order to be able to use it in the future (such as when I call something like `python manage.py retrieve_from_database`)? Is `/var/lib/postgresql` even the right directory, and would `boot2docker` have access to it given that it's apparently limited to `/Users/`?

Thank you!

Comment: Is Auto-Commit set to true, or are you committing your changes manually?

Comment: auto-commit on `sqlalchemy` (that's what I'm using)? I believe I'm committing the changes "manually" --that is, by running `python manage.py insert_into_database` within the main service and letting that commit to Postgres (which worked before I started using Docker). Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Knowing Postgres, a failure to commit seemed the likeliest explanation. I am out of my depth otherwise and shall withdraw.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Politank-Z! I think it's a problem with the way I set up Docker though, because I had no problems with Postgres before I tried it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that Compose creates a *new* version of the `postgresdbdata` container each time it restarts, so the old container and its data gets lost.

A secondary issue is that your data container shouldn't actually be running; data containers are really just a namespace for a volume that can be imported with `--volumes-from`, which still works with stopped containers.

For the time being the best solution is to take the `postgresdbdata` container out of the Compose config. Do something like:

```
$ docker run --name postgresdbdata postgresdb echo "Postgres data container"
Postgres data container
```

The echo command will run and the container will exit, but as long as don't `docker rm` it, you will still be able to refer to it in `--volumes-from` and your Compose application should work fine.

Comment: I see... So what can I do, Adrian?

Comment: @miguel5 You caught me in between drafts - I've updated my answer.

Comment: it's not compose's fault: "When docker-compose up runs, if it finds any containers from previous runs, it copies the volumes from the old container to the new container. This process ensures that any data you’ve created in volumes isn’t lost." (https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/#/preserve-volume-data-when-containers-are-created)